# Local invertibility with Cauchy-Riemann equations and $Df\neq0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, analytic-functions

Question

> $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^2} $ is smooth (i.e. $\in C^{\infty}$) and satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations i.e. $\frac{\partial f_1} {\partial x}=\frac{\partial f_2} {\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial f_1} {\partial y}=-\frac{\partial f_2} {\partial x}$.
>
> If $f$ is locally invertible at $x_0$, then $Df(x_0)\neq0$.

I want to solve this question without complex analysis.

I think since locally invertible, there exists $g(y)$ such that $g(f(x))=x$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$.

But I can't show that local invertiblity implies local inverse is differentiable.

If I know that, I think I can show $Df(x_0)\neq0$ by differentiating $g(f(x))=x$.

Help me!!

Comment: I do not think it is the content of the inverse function theorem. It is rather a converse of the IFT. So CR equation is not irrelevant.

Comment: @Alex M. You mean that local invertibility implies such inverse is differentiable?

Comment: @AlexM. The OP wants "to solve this question without complex analysis."